# Expl3 - how to deal with spaces in a text?

Tags: spacing, expl3

What is the good practise to preserve the spaces when one deals with text parts ?

I read that space caracters are suppressed in a token list. I tried with a string too.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    ]

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase,% or MatchLowercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Pythagore}{m}{%
\tl_new:N \l_text_tl
\str_new:N \l_text_str

\tl_set:Nn \l_text_tl {Dans\ le\ triangle\ ...\ rectangle\ en\ #1,\ on\ utlise\ le\ theorème\ de\ Pythagore:}

\str_set:Nn \l_text_str {Dans\ le\ triangle\ ...\ rectangle\ en\ #1,\ on\ utlise\ le\ theorème\ de\ Pythagore:}

\l_text_tl

% how to have a new line

\l_text_str

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Pythagore{A B}

Dans le triangle ... rectangle en A B, on utlise le theorème de Pythagore:

\end{document}
```

Comment: `~` is a space in expl3 syntax areas

Comment: "I read that space caracters are suppressed in a token list. I tried with a string too." is a misunderstanding it is not that the individual commands handle spaces and discardthem `\ExplSyntacOn` makes the space character be ignored so it never produces a space token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. There is a lot things to read, and they mix up ;-)

Comment: @Tarass I don't think this is logical, if you are adding lots of texts it seems simpler to write them outside expl3 syntax to use normal spaces. This example is a bit nonsense, could you add a real example so that we can help with a better way to solve your problem?

Comment: @Manuel I'am curious and want to explore how to use expl3. My goal as a first try is to make a macro that automats a Pythagore calculation in standart format I use to make correction. Basically two paramerters ABC the triangle name, x,y the two known dimensions. It's just an exercice. If you have a better idea...

Comment: @Tarass I mean that this example is not useful because we cannot show you a complete way of doing this without you showing a bit more. The answer is substitute spaces with `~`, and blank lines with `\par`. But I would make a macro so that I can write text easily outside expl3 syntax and use normal spacing to add the “text information” to your process.

Comment: I would like to make macro `\Pyt{A,B,D}{45,50}` and `\Pyt*{BCD}{75,72}` that produce this sort of output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n4qcw2d6eh04tr/bob.png?dl=0 doing all the calculations by itself, text in a minipage with an hfill between text and calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` the catcode of `~` is changed to space.
So `~` can be used as a space in your `expl3` code blocks.
Additionally `\tl_new:N` and `\str_new:N` should only be called once, so they do not belong in a command.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    ]

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase,% or MatchLowercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_text_tl
\str_new:N \l_text_str    
\NewDocumentCommand{\Pythagore}{m}{%


\tl_set:Nn \l_text_tl {Dans~le~triangle~...~rectangle~en~#1,~on~utlise~~le~theorème~de~Pythagore:}

\str_set:Nn \l_text_str {Dans~le~triangle~...~rectangle~en~#1,~on~utlise~le~theorème~de~Pythagore:}

\l_text_tl

% how to have a new line

\l_text_str

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Pythagore{A B}

Dans le triangle ... rectangle en A B, on utlise le theorème de Pythagore:

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this very case, what is the best practise : `tl_` or `str_` ? And how to force a newline equivalent of jump a line in normal-old-previous synthax.

Comment: If you want to force a newline you can always use `\\ ` or `\par` to have a new paragraph. The choice between `tl` and `str` depends on the usage. In your example there is no need for any of them, so it is hard to say which would be "better". This looks more like a string, so `str`, but if you for example want to allow `\\ ` or `\par` inside your variable, you need a `tl` instead of a `str`.